# button submitting too early

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-listener

My button is submitting my form too early. When i click on my button, it is supposed to create a textarea, which i want to write in and then click on the button again to submit it. Its does create the textarea, but i never get the chance to write anything, because it submits right after the textarea is created. Any solution how to avoid this?

Javascript

```
function createEmailField(event) {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if (name == "") {
        window.alert("Mata in ditt namn");
    }
    else if (name.search(/^[A-Za-z]+$/) == -1) {
        window.alert("Mata in ett namn med bokstäver");
    }
    else {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hej " + name + "!"));
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hur når vi dig?"));
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Epost:"));
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("id", "email");
        input.setAttribute("name", "email");
        newDiv.appendChild(input);
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        var callButton = document.getElementById("button");
        form.insertBefore(newDiv, callButton);
        removeEvent(callButton, "click", createEmailField, false);
        addEvent(callButton, "click", createTextArea, false);
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        email.onkeypress = prevent;
        removeEvent(document.getElementById("name"), "click", createEmailField, false);
    }
}

function createTextArea(event) {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (email == "") {
        alert("Mata in ditt email");
    }
    else if (email.search(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/) == -1) {
        window.alert("Mata in ett korrekt email");
    }
    else {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Vad har du för fråga om vår verksamhet?"));
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        var textArea = document.createElement("textArea");
        textArea.setAttribute("id", "question");
        textArea.setAttribute("name", "question");
        textArea.cols = "30";
        textArea.rows = "5";
        newDiv.appendChild(textArea);
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Vi kommer att svara dig via: " +   email));
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        newDiv.appendChild(br);
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        var callButton = document.getElementById("button");
        form.insertBefore(newDiv, callButton);
        removeEvent(document.getElementById("email"), "click", createTextArea, false);
        callButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    }
}

function prevent(event) {
    if ((window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13) || (event && event.keyCode == 13))  {
        if (window.event) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        } else if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}

function init() {
    var callButton = document.getElementById("button");
    addEvent(callButton, "click", createEmailField, false);
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    name.onkeypress = prevent;
}
window.onload = init;
```

HTML

```
<h2> Frågeformulär </h2>
<form id="form" method="post" action="http://student.ts.mah.se/da123aht11/echoscript.php">
    <div>
        Vad heter du?... 
        <br /><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="skicka" value="Skicka" id="button">
</form>
```

Comment: I think that you mean to call `prevent` in `createTextArea`, but you don't.

Comment: i tried with prevent. but instead of submitting, it started created new textareas, even though i removed the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DrWooolie You might want to use `event.preventDefault();` this piece of code will stop the actual behaviour of the element, button in this case, or it can also work on anchor click events.

[More Info here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: i tried with preventDefault. but instead of submitting, it started created new textareas, even though i removed the event

Comment: though you have created the prevent method but you are calling at the wrong place. At the moment, its on key press of textbox and that doesn't care about the click of the button. instead using prevent for textbox use it for button. You might also want to check if the textbox is null or empty or doesn't validate as per you needs, then show a message below the textbox.